# How can I make effective idle game numbers?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bigint

Numbers get so big they go negative.

I'm trying to make an idle game in flutter, but my numbers get so big the go negative.

I can't find anything anywhere that will raise the limit on int or num. I tried using BigInt but the operations were so slow the app crashed. I want the numbers to go on for infinity in scientific notation but at the moment it goes up to e+18 or something like that before it wraps over to -6755779T or something like that. I assume I have to make my own number class, but I can't think of an effective way to do that. I do want to keep the numbers precise and I don't need support for negative numbers or decimals.

Edit:
I ended up making my own number class
https://pastebin.com/Hhp3CbB8

```
IdleNumb sub(IdleNumb? number) {
if (number != null) {
  for (int i = number.numbs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    while (numbs[i] < number.numbs[i]) {
      numbs[i + 1] -= 1;
      numbs[i] = numbs[i].toInt() + 94868329;
    }

    numbs[i] = numbs[i].toInt() - number.numbs[i].toInt();
    fixNum();
  }
}

return this;}
```

whenever I perform the sub function it seems to crash my app. all the other functions seem to work fine it's only when ever sub is called that the app crashes. Most problems I have had, had a debugger printout and the app closes in the emulator. With this crash the emulator freezes up altogether and the debugger just stops without printing anything.

Comment: Just combine multiple large unsigned integers. When your "low" integer reaches its maximum value, add 1 to the "high" integer and set the low back to 0. Wrap this up in a class.  You can combine more than 2 integers if you want/need.

Comment: `BigInt` operations are, of course, slower, but that shouldn't be a factor in this use case. Why don't you include some code to show what operations you are performing that you think are causing your app to crash?